# Initialize container, failing when executing useradd in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

When running my azure pipeline I run into the below error when trying to initialize a container.

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "useradd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

The snippet of the pipeline where it fails

```yaml
resources:
  containers:
  - container: linux2
    image: amazonlinux:latest
    options: --user 0:0

stages:
  - stage: build_stage    
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      demands:
        - msbuild
        - visualstudio
        - vstest
    
    jobs:
      - job: build_job

        container: linux2

        steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: true
```

This seems like it could potentially be a permissions issue but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `amazonlinux:latest` doesn't have `useradd` command.

AzDev creates the container from the image, then it adds a new user and add this user to sudoers file (even if you don't have `sudo` in your image), and only after that it runs the container.

So the easiest approach is just to change an image. Also you can take `amazonlinux:latest` and add `useradd` and use it in your pipeline.

Comment: Ok I see, that makes sense thank you very much. I need the amazonlinux image because I need the image to match the OS of the deployment environment but what you've said now will give me a way to go forward. Thank you